# Is there a snippet search engine for Git?

Tags: git

I begin to have a lot of projects stored on my server (used as a git server). Sometimes I want to refer to my old code.

Is there a snippet search engine for Git ?
Better, a plugin that can be integrated in Redmine :) ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Define "snippet" and "search engine" in the context of git. This makes no sense.

Comment: Search engine only on last version of projects, its not possible ?

Comment: So simple.... ok down tuning my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

```
git log --all -i --pickaxe-regex -S'InterestingClassOrFunction'
```

Things like this have already been successfully integrated in gitweb and other web clients

---

**edit:** Since you've added a comment stating you wanted to look only in the last version, that makes it a hell of a lot simpler :

```
 man git-grep
 git grep theWord
```

You could still combine this with a for-each-ref to scan across all known branches/tags